# "The label is already a ground truth" happens when importing the images

Tags: google-cloud-platform, x-ray

When I import 100 images into the dataset, but only 99 images are imported successfully. A warning is reported:
"Failed to import some images".

The error messages: **The label is already a ground truth**.

[The images I was importing are Chest X-Ray Images.](https://www.kaggle.com/paultimothymooney/chest-xray-pneumonia)

Comment: can you provide more information.. such as which ML API ...or is this AutoML that you are usiing.. also can you post the full stacktrace

Answer (score 2):

The issue you are facing is most likely due to duplicate images in the GCS bucket you are using to upload your training data to. 
If you are attempting to create your dataset and train the model and it is not your first attempt to do so. 
Make sure that either you use a different bucket, or empty the bucket before retrying. 
The error is almost always due to duplicates in the training data.

For a clearer understanding of the Ground truth concept see the attached documentation [Ground Truth](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/continuous-evaluation/#ground_truth)

I was able to recreate your error following this tutorial [AutroML Quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/quickstart), before training I ensured there were duplicates, and I recreated the needed csv file, in doing this I was able to generate "The label is already a ground truth" error message..